# Working with Intel SSE SIMD intrinsics

Tags: c, sse, icc

I have a question regarding the various arithmetic operations for Intel SSE intrinsics.
what is the difference between doing a _mm_add_ps Vs. _mm_add_epi8/16/32? I want to make sure that my data is aligned at all times.

In a sample code when I do this:

```
 __m128 u1 = _mm_load_ps(&V[(i-1)]);
```

I get a segmentation fault. But when I do this:

```
 __m128 u1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&V[(i-1)]);
```

It works fine.

Since I want my data aligned i declared the array like this:

```
 posix_memalign((void**)&V, 16, dx*sizeof(float));
```

Can someone help explain this.

Comment: You're asking something about different additions and something about alignment, what do you actually want to know? The difference between the different adds is what data types they treat the data as.

Answer (score 4):

`_mm_add_ps` add `float`s together, where `_mm_add_epi8/16/32` adds integers, which are not floating point numbers.

`_mm_loadu_ps` does **not** require your floats to be 16byte (128bit) aligned, whereas `_mm_load_ps` does require 16byte alignment.

So if you get a seg fault on the first one, your alignment is wrong.

On the `posix_memalign` page it says this:

> The posix_memalign() function shall fail if:
>
> [EINVAL] The value of the alignment parameter is not a power of two
>   multiple of sizeof( void *).

I'm not sure that `sizeof(float)` == `sizeof(void*)` ??
Per [this](http://ideone.com/DNJlc), it seems to be the same in C (on a 32bit system).  Ok, a little trickery here, because the size of a pointer is normally the size of the CPU register width, 32bit or 64bit (8 bytes) depending on the system used, whereas a `float` would normally be 32bit (4 bytes)

Your aligned allocation should look more like this:

```
posix_memalign((void**)&V, 16, dx*sizeof(void*)); //since it will the correct size for your platform.  You can always cast to `float` later on.
```

Comment: Your last statement is definitely not true. `float` is (usually) 4 bytes. `void*` is the size of a pointer. (usually: 4 bytes on 32-bit, 8 bytes on 64-bit)

Comment: @Mysticial yea, I found it rather strange, but why does it print `same` then on my little test.  Perhaps accidentally a 32bit system where a pointer is 4 bytes and the `float` also 4 bytes?

Comment: That case is definitely being compiled on 32-bit. Try 64-bit and it'll be different.

Comment: @Tony the Lion: Thanks for pointing that out. What do you think is the best way to allocate 16 byte data accurately. I used this technique too: __declspec(align(16)) float V[dx * sizeof(float)]; .But this is a static declaration, How can I do it dynamically. When I try to use _aligned_malloc at mentioned here:http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html, my compiler (icc) cannot identify it.

Comment: What compiler are you using? `_align_mallac` is for MSVC.  Use the memalign set of functions for GCC.

Comment: @Tony the Lion: can i use memalign for Intel ICC compiler?

Comment: I would assume so.  The main issue with your code was not `memmalign` but the fact that your `sizeof` param to it was wrong.  See the last edit I made to my answer